# Stop Tunneling Event Trigger in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to capture a TabItem selection changed event, i.e. a ViewModel command is invoked only when user changes tabs. I have this at the moment, the command is invoked successfully but the selection changed is tunnelling down the visual tree and therefore the selection changed is captured all over the tab item not just when the user changes tabs. Is there any way to limit the trigger to just tab changes?:

```
<TabControl Margin="10">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CollapsedExpanderCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TabItem Header="Account" >          
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
```

Comment: I think you must pass the event arguments and set the handled property. other option might be try to have in code behind the selectionchanged and set the e.handled = true and see if the command is also triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event trigger on the `TabItem` bound to an `ICommand in my`viewModel`:`

```
<TabItem Header="Memberships" Margin="0,0,-5,-3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MembershipTabSelectedCommand}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM why don't you use the SelectedItem Dependancy Property and binding a property in your ViewModel, eg:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</TabControl>
```